# The eigenvalues of $D^{-1} A $ for $A$ an adjacency matrix of a simple graph with no isolated vertices, and $D$ its degree matrix.

Tags: graph-theory, machine-learning

Suppose we have a simple graph $G$ with no isolated nodes (i.e. each node $v$ has $deg(v) \geq 1$)

In deep learning, in particular graph convolution algorithms, it seems popular as one form of normalization to multiply features per node of a graph by $D^{-1}A$ (for $D$ the degree matrix of $A$) rather than $A$. An explanation given by Kipf [here](https://tkipf.github.io/graph-convolutional-networks/#fn1) notes:

> The second major limitation is that $A$
> is typically not normalized and therefore the multiplication with $A$
> will completely change the scale of the feature vectors (we can understand that by looking at the eigenvalues of $A$
> ). Normalizing $A$
> such that all rows sum to one, i.e. $D^{−1}A$
> , where $D$
> is the diagonal node degree matrix, gets rid of this problem.

I see why $A$ may have eigenvalues larger than $1$, for instance the adjacency matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0\\\ 1 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$ has largest eigenvalue $\sqrt{2}$, causing features multiplied with $A$ to explode as layers stack on, similar to weight matrices in recurrent neural networks, but I'm not sure what the range of eigenvalues of $D^{-1} A$ is. Any insights or references appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\eqdef{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}$
The study of the eigenvalues and eigenvalues and related properties of non-negative matrices is known as [Perron-Frobenius theory](https://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/stefan.guettel/ma/protected/nonneg.pdf).  Your matrix $\ D^{-1}A\ $ is [row-stochastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix), and the theory tells us that the magnitudes of the eigenvalues of such matrices all lie within the interval $\ [0,1]\ $.  The column vector $\ \mathbf{1}\eqdef(1,1,\dots,1)^T\ $ is obviously a right eigenvector of $\ D^{-1}A\ $ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\ 1\ $. When the matrix has some special properties, such as [irreducibility or primitivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem#Classification_of_matrices), a little more can be said about its eigenvalues and eigenvectors.  Your matrix $\ D^{-1}A\ $ will be irreducible if its corresponding graph is connected, and it will be primitive if, in addition, the graph contains a cycle with an odd number of edges.

There's an extensive literature on the Perron-Frobenius theory, and you'll find a comprehensive exposition in any good book on non-negative matrices. I can recommend [Eugene Seneta's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eugene_Seneta) text, [Non-Negative Matrices: An Introduction to Theory and Applications](https://archive.org/details/nonnegativematri00esen_0/page/n9/mode/1up).

Comment: There's also an excellent chapter about nonnegative matrices in Carl D. Meyer's Matrix Analysis and Applied Linear Algebra, as well as in Horn and Johnson's Matrix Analysis.